# Using URL to send data to a server

Tags: html, lamp

I am looking for a way to interpret data in a URL, server side.
Client side, I can control what the URL is, and I can programmatically produce Data for the URL, but I do not have direct access to the source code.

So ultimately, I am trying to build an online High Score system, for an offline game.

I have access to Azure and my dedicated LAMP server. I would like for my server to wait for a connections that use a URL something like "http://www.myappserver19002393859.com/HighScores?UserID=2fb44e3888?Score=25250" 
I want to get the UserID & Score from the URL and then redirect to another page with the High Score Table...

Any suggestions?

(Edit: I can do anything server side, it is only client side where I have limitations.)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What you've described is trivial to implement in PHP.

Comment: I am familiar with PHP, but I am not a pro. I guess I got lost since I am somewhat locked on the client side of the app.

Comment: my question would be how do I parse the info I want out of the URL in PHP. Since the App is only the client until the link is clicked... after that its just a browser, so you are right... I guess its nothing too complicated. I don't have experience with doing this type of thing with the URL in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's `$_GET` collection. It contains the key/value pairs of a URI's querystring.

In the example you've given, it would look like this:

#### HighScoresHandler.php

```
<?php
$userId = $_GET['UserID'];
$score  = $_GET['Score'];

// Validation

if( empty( $userId ) || empty( $score ) ) {
    echo "No UserID or Score provided.";
    exit();
}
$score = intval( $score );
if( $score === 0 ) {
    echo "Invalid score specified.";
    exit();
}

// Verification

// TODO: Query your database to ensure the user specified by $userID exists.
// Make sure you do this safely as not to be subject to SQL injection.

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserID = @userId";

// Action

$sql = "INSERT INTO HighScores ( UserID, Score ) VALUES ( @userId, @score )";


?>
```

Note that you would be advised to implement some form of MAC (Message Authentication Code) or some other system to verify that a score is real, otherwise there is nothing stopping anyone from submitting bogus scores using forged HTTP requests (this is why you sometimes see insanely high scores posted to online scoreboards).

Comment: $userId = intval( $userId );

Comment: Thank you very much. I would up vote but I haven't gotten enough rep yet... Its hard to be the smart kid in the smart kid club.

Comment: @lvil In the Question the userId was not an integer, so I didn't perform any casting/conversion for the userId, but I did for the score.

Comment: @Dai right, haven't noticed it, anyway there has to be some validation here